# Undefined variable of a sum in PHP

Tags: php

I am making a shopping cart in php, its almost done and now i'm making the total of all items in the cart with:

```
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$total=$price+$total;

}
```

It returns "Undefined variable:total" but it works anyways and i got the correct result. Its very strange and i don't want this error showing up.

When i define the variable like in the example below it doesn't give me the right result, just gives me the last value of the '$price' variable and not the sum.

```
$total=0;
$total=$price+$total;
```

Can someone give me a hint, seems very simple to solve but i can't do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your actual implementation? What are $total, $price

Comment: Please show us your **full** error message + The outputs of: `var_dump($total);` (before and after the loop) + `var_dump($price);`

Comment: most of use would use: `$total+=$price;`

Comment: move your `$total=0` above your `while` and the `undefined` error should be gone. The reasons is clear, you're trying to add `$price` to undefined variable.

Comment: @Dagon, your solution would still throw an error.

Comment: @kldcruz of course, so easy, wasnt thinking straight. Thank you, it works :)

Comment: Can i put your answer as the right one?

Comment: @kdlcruz it was a tip not a full solution- of course `$total` has to exist first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your

```
$total=0;
```

above your while and the **undefined** error should be gone. The reasons is clear, you're trying to add `$price` to **undefined** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Move total above the while.
and then use += for less verbose code.

```
$total=0;
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $total+=$price;
}
```